# Migrating from TFS 2013 to Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I'm try to migrate our on-premise source code from TFS2013 to Visual Studio Online but I'm being presented with an error.  Error at bottom.

I have recreated the projects in VSO, even recreated VSO.  Deleted C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

Uninstalled OpsHub and deleted C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility

I'm using Version 1.2.0.000

Any advise would be brilliant.

Thanks

```
ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl) - OH-CONFIG-0053: Error while validating metadata for source and target system, because of OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getFiledCollection. Server Error : Error occured while fetching metdata for Test Suite:   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementWebService4.QueryTestPlans(ResultsStoreQuery query)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestPlanHelper.Query(String queryText)
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSTestSuiteClient.getFieldCollection(String entityName, String projectName) in e:\5.7Checkout\VSMUOpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSTestSuiteUtility.cs:line 625 caused by : TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate]».
com.opshub.eai.config.exception.ConfigServiceException: OH-CONFIG-0053: Error while validating metadata for source and target system, because of OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getFiledCollection. Server Error : Error occured while fetching metdata for Test Suite:   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementWebService4.QueryTestPlans(ResultsStoreQuery query)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestPlanHelper.Query(String queryText)
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSTestSuiteClient.getFieldCollection(String entityName, String projectName) in e:\5.7Checkout\VSMUOpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSTestSuiteUtility.cs:line 625 caused by : TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate]».
    at com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.generateIntegrationsAndMappings(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:657)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.generateIntegrationAndMappings(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:386)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl.generateIntegration(ConfigServiceImpl.java:209)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl.generateIntegrations(ConfigServiceImpl.java:157)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a961247.CGLIB$generateIntegrations$15(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a961247$$FastClassByCGLIB$$cad9724a.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ServiceInterception.intercept(ServiceInterception.java:44)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a961247.generateIntegrations(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigService.generateIntegrations(ConfigService.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.opshub.eai.tfs.exception.OIMTFSApiExcpetion: OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getFiledCollection. Server Error : Error occured while fetching metdata for Test Suite:   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementWebService4.QueryTestPlans(ResultsStoreQuery query)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestPlanHelper.Query(String queryText)
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSTestSuiteClient.getFieldCollection(String entityName, String projectName) in e:\5.7Checkout\VSMUOpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSTestSuiteUtility.cs:line 625 caused by : TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate]».
    at com.opshub.eai.tfs.adapter.TFSClient.getFiledCollection(TFSClient.java:160)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.generateIntegrationsAndMappings(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:490)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Are you using a custom or modified build process template?

Answer (score 0):

From Error it seems that Start Date field is deleted form Test Plan. Currently OpsHub Migration Utility do not support Migration of Customized Test Entities such as Test Plan/Test Suite/Test Run/Test Result. You can rectify this in Test Plan in both TFS and VSO instances.